# MediaWiki markup equivalent of WMD live-previewing editor? (not WYSIWYG)

Tags: mediawiki, markdown, markup, wmd, wmd-editor

What editor like the [WMD editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) can be recommended, but using MediaWiki markup instead of Markdown?  Our site is already using MediaWiki markup, but we want a slicker editor without changing Markup completely.

Requirements include:

- live preview of formatted text underneath the markup you're typing
- a toolbar for common formatting (bold, italic, links, bullets, numbered-list, code, etc.)
- keyboard shortcuts for each toolbar button (for example, CTRL+B for bold)
- Undo/redo via keyboard shortcuts (CTRL+Z/CTRL+Y) or toolbar buttons
- works well in the usual set of popular browsers (including Internet Explorer 6!)
- open source would be preferred

I've found a few options at *[WYSIWYG editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor)*, but all of these seem to be WYSIWYG editors which is not exactly what I want since full-on WYSIWYG editors tend to be bug-prone and complicated at the markup level. Instead we want a plain-text markup editor with a client-side previewer, plus some UI niceties (toolbar, undo, keyboard shortcuts) to make editing markup easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since the time this question was asked, a new WYSIWYG editor for MediaWiki was developed, [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor). Unlike its predecessors, it is a *de facto* standard. Note that purely live preview for a wikitext editor would not be much simpler than this because MW wikitext can be insanely complex so a complicated parser would be needed, just like [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) used by VisualEditor.